# Maximum Flow in Directed Graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am reading about the Maximum Flow Problem [Here](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/ford-fulkerson-algorithm-for-maximum-flow-problem/). I could not understand the initiation behind the  Residual Graph. Why we are considering a back edge while calculating the flow.
Can anyone help me in understanding the concept of Residual Graph.
How the Algorithm changes in Undirected Graph

Answer (score 0):

A residual graph is a graph which shows if you can have more flow than you currently do (since you start out with 0 flow). When you've "solved" the problem, you shouldn't be able to get to the sink from the source using your residual graph (since the residual graph shows if more flow is available).

Think of the normal graph as velocity, and the residual graph as acceleration. The residual graph basically shows the change in velocity.

The algorithm shouldn't change in an undirected graph. An undirected graph is the same as a directed graph where arrows point in both directions instead of no directions. More about that here:
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/677743/finding-the-max-flow-of-an-undirected-graph-with-ford-fulkerson

Answer (score 0):

The residual graph is what is left of the network after you remove the flow you've already passed through. Say you have an edge AB with capacity 10 and the current flow moves 7 units through AB then in the residual graph you should have an edge AB with capacity 3 (what is left) and an edge BA with capacity 7 (this appears because you can get flow back by removing it from the previous solution; That is because if you find a way from source to B and from A to the sink then you can redirect the previous solution to not use the edge AB, or use less of it).

To make it more clear see this image [image].
Say the first path you find is s, u, v, t and you push 10 flow through it. Now you can find in the residual graph the path s,v,u,t (even if the vu edge doesn't exist in the original graph) and push 5 flow through it. So what happened is that 5 units of flow that were going from u to v are now redirected to go to t, and the 5 units that were coming from u to v are now coming from s.

If you have an undirected graph you can replace an edge AB with a directed edge AB and a directed edge BA with the same capacity as the original undirected edge. You can't have flow going in both directions because you get the same solution by cancelling out the smaller one. There's nothing to gain by sending the flow back and forth.