# Solving a problem_ Using Maximum Flow

Tags: algorithm, graph

I am trying to solve this [Problem](https://www.hackerearth.com/march-clash-16/algorithm/the-great-charzeh/description/).

Problem Statement is as follows

The great Charzeh is playing a game with Joffrey Baratheon. There are `n` knights in seven kingdoms. `i-th` knight has strength equal to `ai (0 ≤ ai < m)`. There are also `n+m-1 numbers f0, f1, ..., fn+m-2` on the walls of black castle.

"The game" consists of two turns. In the first turn, Charzeh chooses a permutation of numbers `0, 1, ..., n-1 like p0, p1, ..., pn-1`.

In the second turn Joffrey chooses and integer `i (0 ≤ i < n)` and then beheads `fpi + ai` random residents of Winterfell. Charzeh is kind and Joffrey is cruel. That's why Charzeh tries to minimize and Joffrey tries to maximize the number beheaded people.

If they both play optimally, how many people will die?

For a Input:

```
7 0 9 1
5 61 53 6 7 72 75 42 5 79 91 5 16
```

Answer is `7`

When I am going through Editorials it is showing it can be solved using Maximum Min um Flow. I don't know how this algorithms works here. Can anyone can explain me how to solve this i.e. provide me a idea how this algorithm works here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only value that matters is the `max(fpi + ai)`. So the question really is what is the minmum value `X` such that there is at least a permutation where `fpi + ai <= X` for all values of i.

To check if such a permutation exists you can create a bipartite graph. On one side you have nodes corresponding to positions of `f`, and on the other you have nodes corresponding to values of `a`. You have an edge between `f[x]` and `a[y]` iff `f[x] + a[y] <= X`, that is if a permutation where you pair `f[x]` and `a[y]` is suitable for the solution. All the weights should be 1. You can now compute max flow over the resulting graph. If you are able to push n units of flow (connect all the n nodes you have) then that is a permutation that satisfies the initial condition(`fpi + ai <= X`).

So now all you have to do is a binary search for the minimum `X` where you are still able to find a flow of n units in the corresponding graph. If I'm not mistaking the complexity will be `O(log(N+M)*N^3)` the log is from the binary search and the `N^3` from the flow algorithm.

You could also try to use the fact that when you increase `X` the corresponding graph is strictly a superset of the original one (you don't remove edges by increasing X). This means that the partial solution you found so far for the lower value of X is a reasonable starting point for computing the flow for the increased value of X. Works the other way too but it's a lot more messy (you need to find the edges used that don't satisfy the condition anymore and find an alternative connection in the graph). But unless you need to squeeze every last bit of performance I wouldn't bother with the extra complexity.

Comment: Thanks !! Could you answer this  [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36111825/maximum-flow-in-directed-graph/36112067#36112067)

Comment: I tried to implement the [Code](http://ideone.com/3vXvWm) but getting wrong answer.... Please Help !!!!

Comment: I added an answer to that question as well, but I'm sure you can find better explanations on the web. As for the code, I'm not super familiar with Java, you could try codereview.stackexchange.com.